# Sed insert value when matching pattern

Tags: xml, sed

i have a xml file and i need to insert a value contains in a variable  between  `PurchaseOrderNumber="99503"`.
For exemple  if `$value=001` i will have `PurchaseOrderNumber="00199503"`.
I tried many commands with sed but nothing work the last one i tried is `sed '/^PurchaseOrderNumber=\"/s/^/001/' file.xml  > output.xml`
can you help me on that

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

        <PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99503" OrderDate="1999-10-20">
          <Address Type="Shipping">
            <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
            <Street>123 Maple Street</Street>
            <City>Mill Valley</City>
            <State>CA</State>
            <Zip>10999</Zip>
            <Country>USA</Country>
          </Address>
          <Address Type="Billing">
            <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
            <Street>8 Oak Avenue</Street>
            <City>Old Town</City>
            <State>PA</State>
            <Zip>95819</Zip>
            <Country>USA</Country>
          </Address>
     </PurchaseOrder>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed 's/PurchaseOrderNumber="/PurchaseOrderNumber="001/g'`

Also, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/624766).

Answer (score 1):

Use a proper XML handling tool to process XML. For example, I used [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2):

```
open file.xml ;
insert text '001' prepend /PurchaseOrder/@PurchaseOrderNumber ;
save :b ;
```

Answer (score 0):

thank's that work, i also found a way so i post it if it's can help anyone

```
sed 's/PurchaseOrderNumber=\"/&001/' file.xml > output.xml
```